Space UN – non human focalpoints
There's a trope in science fiction in which there's a race/species (usually the protagonists of the story  that achieves inter galactic travel). They head out in to the wider galaxy (sometimes galaxies depending on setting), they then encounter many alien species who for various  reasons are often at war with each other but this race acts as some kind of inter-species peacekeeper, a mutual ally for all those various races to form around and stop fighting each other.
The obvious examples are humans in Star Trek – they first met Vulcans, then Klingons and then others. The Vulcan and Andorians hate each other but but with humanity's introduction and a long time frame,  Starfleet and then the Federation arose, with Vulcans, Humans and Andorians.
What is the earliest example of this trope in which a species that has helped to bring a divided galaxy together to bring about some level of peace and cooperation?

So you're asking about a sort of Roman Empire in space, which establishes something like a Pax Romana? So you want the first example of an interstellar empire?

Is the "Federation of Stars" in Edmond Hamilton's Interstellar Patrol series from 1929 the sort of thing you're looking for, or not? It's a multispecies organization that keeps the peace in the galaxy, but it doesn't seem to be dominated by any one species.

@Matt Bartlett  I that that intra galactic travel is travel within a galaxy, and inter galactic travel is travel between galaxies.

I thought the trope was galactic peace enforced by robots! The Day the Earth Stood Still 1951  https://youtu.be/ASsNtti1XZs?si=mJMbpiD372aMp4li

@user14111 no not an empire where membership is forced or subjugated but something like the federation where membership is applied for, but one where humans aren't some sort of lynchpin holding it together. or part of the initial formation.

The earliest example is probably E. E. Smith's Arisians introducedin 1937 in the magazine publication of Galactic Patrol, who promote the development of other, less-powerful species (including humans) and eventually establish the Lensmen, who act as interstellar police. Smith's Arisians certainly inspired the Oans (who created the Green Lantern Corps) and probably inspired Julian May's Lylmik who established the Galactic Milieu (a similar interstellar UN).

There are many space opera examples of empires and federations which bring peace by conquering planets and/or by persuading planets to join for mutual defense and cooperation.
The Federation of Stars in Edmond "World Wrecker" Hamilton's Interstellar Patrol stories might be the earliest example.
It was first seen in "The Star-Stealers" Weird Tales February 1929.
https://archive.org/details/Weird_Tales_v13n02_1929-02_AT-sas/page/n6/mode/1up
But there were earlier stories of interstellar travel and thus some earlier stories of interstellar wars.  And some of those early stories of interstellar wars might not be just planet against planet or star system against star system, but might have involved interstellar empires, federations, unions, etc. fighting against each other.

In "The Star-Stealers" Hamilton calls his interstellar organization the Federation of Stars.

@user14111  The interstellar government is the Federation of Stars, the interstellar police/military force is the Interstellar Patrol.  Like the United Federation of Planets and Starfleet.

Maybe not the best fit, but the Overlords from Arthur C. Clarke's 1953 novel Childhood's End kind of go in that direction. However, while they do bring peace (ending the tensions between the US and the USSR), they appear as conquerors rather than allies. Also, since they come to planets before the respective civilization develops space travel, they initially seem to be more intra-species peace keepers, rather than inter-species.
Later in the novel, it is revealed

 that the Overlords are fostering the progression of species of individuals into a shared mind, eventually merging into the Overmind, a galaxy-spanning intelligence (a fate denied to the Overlords themselves), thus ensuring galaxy-wide harmony after a fashion.

